# untar multiple tar files with identical names to a concatenated/appended file

Tags: python, bash, unix, gzip, tar

My situation is as follows:
have a couple of tar files called tar1.tar.gzip, tar2.tar.gzip etc.
each one contains a different file but with the same name - fn.csv.

if I untar one after the other to the same dir, I get the last one,
Is there a way to make tar append the content rather than stepping over it?

so far, I've added copy to unique file name after each untar and then concatenated all the files, is there a more direct way (python or bash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU tar:

```
fileno="42"
tar -xvzf "tar${fileno}.tar.gzip" --transform 's/.*/file'"${fileno}"'.csv/' --show-transformed-names
```

This extracts `tar42.tar.gzip` to current directory and names its file to `file42.csv`. I assume that the archive contains only one file.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option for tar to do that. To do better than your current solution, you would need to write your own untar that appends to the current files.

Comment: ... Or just untar to different directories and then `cat` the extracted files to the final destination.